# Effectively studying research papers

Tags: academic-life

How to read one to more research papers that are nearly 20- 30 pages in a short time since I have other miscellaneous works ?

Comment: Decide which are the top 5 and read those... You can always come back to the others...

Comment: Have you tried googling this? There are some excellent articles out there. After reading those, if you have a specific issue, maybe someone here can help.

Comment: I thought to understand many technical concepts especially the math would be in papers .But most of the articles I found was telling to skim the abstract then to conclusion and results .So I do want to read a complete paper not based on specific problem.that's y I asked here .

Comment: Your question essentially boils down to: _how to be a researcher?_

Comment: That's how Jean Bourgain does it. Paper #1: goes over every little detail, learns everything slowly, takes 3 months total. .... Paper #1001: Looks at the main theorem, then flips to Lemma 3, says, "Aha!", goes to the board and writes the derivation of a result much stronger  than the main theorem. Takes 10 minutes total. Three dots stand for 15-20 years. There is no shorter way but everybody can go this one.

Comment: This isn't worth an answer, but it helps to always have one or more papers with you wherever you are. If you travel by public transport, especially, you will have a few minutes several times per day to give at least a light (breadth) reading. Also, carry some means of taking notes on what you read. If you carry paper copies you can make notations there, but I use and advocate index cards for note taking as they are flexible for later use - organizational, etc. Find a way to use otherwise "wasted" moments productively.

Answer (score 4):

There is a really good document by Columbia University that explains [how to read a paper](https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/netbib/efficientReading.pdf) (focused in science and technology). The key is to read firstly on *breadth*, getting the best information from the abstract, figures, tables and so on. And then in *depth* if you think that from the first *diagonal reading* the paper is worth the time to do so.